# Securing Azure web app (easy tables)

Tags: javascript, azure

I have created a backend for an android app (xamarin.android) usng Azure EasyTables. Now everything's working but I also want to access my EasyTables db from a website.

Currently as a test, I'm using the Azure mobile javascript sdk. As an absolute beginner, I really don't have an idea how I can make this secure. I have lines of code like

```
var MobService = WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient;
var client = new MobService(MYAPPURL);
var reportsTable = client.getTable("rp_Table");
var totalActs;
var query = reportsTable;
query.where(function (){return this.LicensePlate == lplate || this.ReporterId == uname;})
  .includeTotalCount().read().done(function (results){ });
```

all of which are EXPOSED to anyone. Where do I even begin to look to secure this? Is there a way to have some sort of stored procedure in Azure EasyTables so I can just disable anonymous CRUD permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable anonymous CRUD permissions on the table via the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com) like this:

> navigate to your App Service -> **Easy tables** -> select the table -> **Change permissions**

[image]

For more information, please refer to the following documentation articles:

[How to: Use authentication claims with your tables](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk.md#how-to-require-authentication-for-access-to-tables)

[30 DAYS OF ZUMO.V2 (AZURE MOBILE APPS): DAY 6 – PERSONAL TABLES](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/)

Comment: Thanks for this. However, here's my problem: I'm expecting anonymous users to use my web app. I'm looking for a way to have a middle-man of sorts to interface with my table while not totally exposing the CRUD operations in my webpage.

Answer (score -1):

Raphael,

Could you try setting the firewall on your EasyTables DB as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-tutorial

You would be able to specify client IP addresses to which you would like access to be granted to.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. To clarify, this would go in to a website. My current concern is that all of my API's credentials and functions are exposed in the html page; anyone can have access to the db right now.